# GCP Flex Template Error: py options not set in envsetup file ... error waiting for container: unexpected EOF

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dataflow

Attempint to use dataflow flex template runner with custom python container image.

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base

ARG WORKDIR=/dataflow/template
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

COPY . .

ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="${WORKDIR}/requirements.txt"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/pipeline_preprocess_preprocess_table.py"

RUN pip install -U -r ./requirements.txt
```

Using the following commands to build/run container:

```
gcloud builds submit --gcs-log-dir $GCSLOGDIR --tag $TEMPLATE_IMAGE .

gcloud dataflow flex-template build $TEMPLATE_PATH --image "$TEMPLATE_IMAGE" --sdk-language "PYTHON" --metadata-file $METADATA_FILE --network $NETWORK --subnetwork $SUBNETWORK --project $PROJECT --worker-region $REGION --service-account-email $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL

gcloud dataflow flex-template run "<pipeline-name>-`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S` " --template-file-gcs-location $TEMPLATE_PATH --parameters <parameter_name>=<parameter_value>...repeat_for_ea --region "$REGION" --project ut-dws-udrc-dev --setup-file setup.py
```

The pipeline runs locally with the direct runner AND the dataflow runner.  Not sure what's breaking.  ANy help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get to fix this by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

So we got to fix this. The documentation at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates is lying, and all environment variables need to be defined, although they can be empty. Our `Dockerfile` has this:

```
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="/app/entrypoint.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="/app/requirements.txt"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_OPTIONS=""
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_EXTRA_PACKAGES=""
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE=""
```