# Dataflow Flex Template: module not found

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to use Dataflow to do some parallel operations in `pandas`. I understand that `pandas` is installed on the workers [nodes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#sdk-for-python_1). But every time I submit a Flex template to Dataflow, I get an error that `pandas` and the custom modules that I wrote cannot be imported.

I've also looked at all the SO posts related to this:

- [Dataflow flex template: ModuleNotFoundError: no module name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341392/dataflow-flex-template-modulenotfounderror-no-module-name)

  - Here I created a `FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_EXTRA_PACKAGES` env var. Oddly enough, setting it to `${WORKDIR}` or `transform_lib` will complain that `Error occurred in the launcher container: could not validate extra package: file transform_lib is a directory`
- [GCP Flex Template Error: py options not set in envsetup file ... error waiting for container: unexpected EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69439953/gcp-flex-template-error-py-options-not-set-in-envsetup-file-error-waiting-f)

  - Currently this is throwing the same error as above.

I've also taken a look at [this](https://medium.com/cts-technologies/building-and-testing-dataflow-flex-templates-80ef6d1887c6) and was able to validate that I was able to import `pandas` and `transform_lib` inside the container.

project structure

```
root/
├─ transform_lib/
│  ├─ utils.py
│  ├─ dataflow/
│  │  ├─ beam.py
├─ deploy/
│  ├─ dataflow/
│  │  ├─ requirements.txt
│  │  ├─ Dockerfile
```

beam.py (I understand that there is a [Dataframe](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) API but in this case, I'm unsure if it will work. Most of the examples are just doing iterations row by row while I need to do operations on a DF resulting from a groupedBy key - more than happy to refactor this)

```
import pandas as pd

from transform_lib.utils import some_function


class DoPandasThings(beam.DoFn):
    """
    Do Pandas things
    """
    def process(self, element):
        # the elements is a tuple with (ID, records as a list of dicts)
        # converting to a dataframe so I can use methods on it
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(element[1]) 
        df = df.replace({None: np.nan})
        df["rolling_sum"] = (
            df["_raw_counts"].rolling(14, min_periods=7).sum()
        )
        df["custom_function" = some_function(df["other_counts"])
 
        ... write to Parquet somehow

       
def run(
    table,
    runtime_args: Optional[PipelineOptions] = None,
) -> None:
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(runtime_args, save_main_session=True)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        _ = (
            pipeline
            | "ReadTable" >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=table)
            | "Grouping" >> beam.GroupBy(lambda x: x["id"])
            | "Pandas" >> beam.ParDo(DoPandasThings())
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--table", required=True, help=("Table to read from"))
    args, runtime_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    run(args.table, runtime_args)
```

setup.py

```
import setuptools


setuptools.setup(
    name="transform_lib",
    version="0.0.0",
    install_requires=[],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python38-template-launcher-base:20221018_RC00

ARG dataflow_file_path
ARG WORKDIR=/opt/dataflow

# creating standardized dataflow directory structure
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

# copying over necessary files
COPY deploy/dataflow/requirements.txt .
COPY transform_lib/dataflow/beam.py .

# kitchen sink env var
# https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates#set_required_dockerfile_environment_variables
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="${WORKDIR}/requirements.txt"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/beam.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE="${WORKDIR}/setup.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_EXTRA_PACKAGES=""
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_OPTIONS=""
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE=""

# following practices listed here:
# https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshoot-templates#python-timeout-polling
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libffi-dev git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install apache-beam[gcp] \
    && pip install -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE \
    # Download the requirements to speed up launching the Dataflow job.
    && pip download --no-cache-dir --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE \
    && pip download --no-cache-dir --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache .

# install local python module
COPY deploy/dataflow/setup.py .
COPY transform_lib transform_lib/
RUN python setup.py install

ENV PIP_NO_DEPS=True
```

Comment: Can you post the errors that you're getting? Are they at the Flex Template launcher phase or workers? What happens if you remove `ENV PIP_NO_DEPS=True`?

Comment: @BrunoVolpato I tried running without `PIP_NO_DEPS` and the same error is returned: `in process NameError: name 'pd' is not defined [while running 'DoPandasThings-ptransform-22']`

Answer (score 0):

you need to import pandas inside the function, according to the dataflow [common-errors](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#name-error)

```py
from transform_lib.utils import some_function


class DoPandasThings(beam.DoFn):
    """
    Do Pandas things
    """
    import pandas as pd
    def process(self, element):
        # the elements is a tuple with (ID, records as a list of dicts)
        # converting to a dataframe so I can use methods on it
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(element[1]) 
        df = df.replace({None: np.nan})
        df["rolling_sum"] = (
            df["_raw_counts"].rolling(14, min_periods=7).sum()
        )
        df["custom_function" = some_function(df["other_counts"])
 
        ... write to Parquet somehow
```